# How to host images using an online service for jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am experimenting with the HTML canvas and practicing HTML and CSS using jsfiddle and need to use my own images. I know that Google Drive and several other sites offer free image hosting, and am wondering if I can use them to import images using  and drawImage();

How can I import my own images to jsfiddle using a link from an online image hosting site?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to be able to host files (images) via http. Any free webhosting site should allow you to connect via an FTP client an upload a file. Once uploaded, you can use the http link to the image within jsfiddle. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service like https://imgbb.com/ and then you can use the URL of the uploaded picture in your JavaScript.